# Why Are there Two Constructors for the Random Class?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I've a question on [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) class constructors. There are two constructors, one with a seed parameter and one without a seed.

What are the use cases to use Random class without a seed (parameterless constructor)? I cannot think any circumstance...

Comment: Well what if you don't have a seed?

Comment: If you specify a Random instance without passing in a seed value, it use the system clock to seed the random value.

Comment: What I meant is that the fact that I don't have a convenient seed would be a use case for a parameter-less Random constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the constructor with the seed, using the same seed value each time will result in the same number sequence being generated each time. This is useful for testing expected scenarios.

You can test using the default constructor (it will use a time-based seed) to test for intermittent scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

A `Random` will always have a seed. The only thing that using the constructor that takes a `seed` parameter does is allow you to use your own seed rather than the one generated for you. If you don't have a convenient way to generate a seed value on your own that will be more "random" than the generated seed (and you're not in a scenario where you need to use a *particular* seed value), then there's no need to supply one.

Comment: It's pretty hard do do worse than the default implementation.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: True, but unless you're instantiating new instances of `Random` within close proximity to each other, the default is most likely good enough.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - The only problem is when you instantiate Random instances in a tight loop. Providing your own seed value will potentially have the same effect.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Agreed, and if you require randomness in a loop you can just declare a single `Random` outside the loop.

Comment: Suppose you have a Web game. Multiple requests might start at the same time, you can't rely on the default (clock) seed for an instance-per-request scenario. You have to take control of the seed.

Comment: @Henk: Just to play devil's advocate, that also assumes that duplicate sequences across different requests (which, if they're at the same time, assumes that these requests correspond to different *sessions*) is not acceptable.